# Connecting a device to an account

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

So the title sounds stupid. I'm not really sure how to really word it, but I want someone to help guide me on what to look for. Little back story first so I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project that involves using an LTE service currently I have a dashboard running on a AWS EC2 web server with a simple user working user login.

I have a raspberry pi that is directly pointed to the dashboard/account via an IP address. I want to know how to do something like giving a device an ID and having it connect to an account. So for example with Nest products you have the QR code on the camera you take a photo and that devices get applied to your account.

Is this even possible with Raspberry Pi(I'm sure anything possible, but is it feasible? If so what should I look into or learn how to do such thing. I know its not something that can be answered in a short paragraph just looking for some guidance.

Comment: so... please explain to me again what are you trying to do, in a different way, please?

Comment: @SergioFlores Say I have a simple Raspberry Pi sensor reads for example temperature. I have a web server in the cloud hosting User accounts and a dashboard that displays temps. Currently right now I have to go in manually map raspberry pi to an account. Now say a friend of mine wants this Raspberry Pi sensor so he goes to the dashboard logins and is able to map the device to his account with like a 6 digit code. I've seen it done with things like Automatic Car Adapter, Nest, and Smartthings. I was just wondering how and what to research in order to do something like that or remotely like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, thanks. Well, I think you need to program this into the pi server app. So currently your Pi is reading a sensor and sending this data to the web server, right? I suppose you have a daemon running, taking readings, and doing an API REST call to the server backend, correct? So what you want is to have a unique code for each pi, sent with the API call, and then on your DB server side,you store all readings related to their unique code.

You don't need to pre-validate this code, there are GUID generators that will create a number for you, guaranteed to be unique for all eternity, so on the PI, you set it up once, to create the PI's code, and use it from then on. Now, server side, then associating a device with a user is a matter of choosing the data associated with a given gui. And I think that covers it.

You can improve on this basic idea by giving it more thought, but I think it's a good starting point! Do let me know if I can help you with anything else!